# Error on Arduino when checking values against an array

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I worked with a buddy to create the below sketch for an Arduino Uno, but we are stuck on a problem. The intent of the code is to read button pushes from 6 buttons that are pins 1-6 on the Uno, then check the stored button pushes against a stored array to see if it is correct.

When you press a button the yellow LED lights up. When you enter five buttons, it checks against the array and gives you a red LED if you are incorrect. If you are correct, it gives you a green LED and then triggers a relay to open.

The code that we have works intermittently, but it doesn't work every time. I don't believe it is a wiring issue, because I can get it to work every time when I am the one pressing the buttons.

I haven't been able to determine a cause of the error. I haven't been able to duplicate the error when I am using it, but it continues to error. Once it errors, I have to restart the Arduino to get it to work again.

My expectation is that it is something in the way that the button presses are stored, or in the way that the counter starts and restarts in the loop.  I am not able to train the users, so it might be that they are holding the buttons down or something like that to make it error.

I am hopeful that it is a simple answer, but I am not skilled in coding so I was hoping for some help.

```
// Button pins
const int button1 = 1;
const int button2 = 2;
const int button3 = 3;
const int button4 = 4;
const int button5 = 5;
const int button6 = 6;
const int grnLed = 11;
const int redLed = 9;
const int yellowLed = 10;
const int openRelay = 7;

const int brightness = 300;

// How long is our code, kind of personal
const int codelen = 5;

// Pin code values must match button pin values
char PIN[codelen] = {
  '4', '1', '5', '3', '2'
};

// Attempted combination
char attempt[codelen] = {
  '0', '0', '0', '0' ,'0'
};

// Attempt count
int z = 0;

void setup() {

  // You've been set up
  pinMode(button1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(openRelay, OUTPUT);

  // Set pullup resistor for buttons
  digitalWrite(button1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(button2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(button3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(button4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(button5, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(button6, HIGH);
  //digitalWrite(openRelay, LOW);
}


void correctPIN()
{
  pulseLED(grnLed, brightness, 3000);
  pulseLED(openRelay, brightness, 1500);
  //analogWrite(openRelay, HIGH);
  //delay(2000);
  //analogWrite(openRelay, LOW);
  z = 0;
}

void incorrectPIN()
{
  pulseLED(redLed, brightness, 2000);

  z = 0;
}

void checkPIN()
{
  int correct = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < codelen; i++)
  {

    if (attempt[i] == PIN[i])
    {
      correct++;
    }
  }
  if (correct == codelen)
  {
    correctPIN();
  }
  else
  {
    incorrectPIN();
  }

  for (int zz = 0; zz < codelen; zz++)
  {
    attempt[zz] = '0';
  }
}


void checkButton(int button){

  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW)
  {
    while (digitalRead(button) == LOW) { } // Do nothing

    // Convert int to string for tracking/compare
    char buttStr = button + '0';
    attempt[z] = buttStr;
    z++;

    //Light up LED so we know botton press worked
    pulseLED(yellowLed, brightness, 500);
  }
}


void pulseLED(int ledpin, int brightness, int msec) {
  analogWrite(ledpin, brightness);
  delay(msec);
  analogWrite(ledpin, LOW);
}


void loop() {

  // Check buttons
  checkButton(button1);
  checkButton(button2);
  checkButton(button3);
  checkButton(button4);
  checkButton(button5);
  checkButton(button6);

  // If number of buttons pressed, z, matches code/pin length then check
  if (z >= codelen)
  {
    checkPIN();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code to handle debouncing.  Have you handled that in hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press a mechanical switch, it's possible for arcing or actual bouncing of the contacts to cause the circuit to open and close several times in rapid succession.

I think the problem is that you haven't "debounced" the button presses, thus, when you click a button once, it can actually register as multiple consecutive presses.

The simplest way to handle this in software is to add a delay after you detect the pin going low and then to check the pin again after the delay.  So, instead of:

```
if (digitalRead(button) == LOW)
{ 
    while (digitalRead(button) == LOW) { } // do nothing
    ...
}
```

You'd do something like:

```
if (digitalRead(button) == LOW)
{
    delay(20);
    if (digitalRead(button) == LOW) {
        ...
    }
}
```

There are more sophisticated approaches, but I bet this solves your immediate problem.

Comment: I was under the impression that setting the internal pull up resistor on the board, and then setting the pins high, would fix the debouncing issues.  So your thought is a simple 20 milisecond delay before checking the button again will probably fix my problem?

Comment: A pull-up resistor just makes it really easy to connect a switch or button to a pin; it doesn't do any debouncing.  Yes, a short delay is generally enough to filter out the noise.  People will argue over how long the delay should be, but I find 20 ms is enough to work well with the push buttons I have without being so long that you miss an actual second press.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided above, here is my updated attempt at the checkButton function:

```
void checkButton(int button){

  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW)
 { 
    delay(20);
    if(digitalRead(button) == LOW)
      while (digitalRead(button) == LOW) { } // do nothing
      //convert int to string for tracking/compare
      char buttStr = button + '0';
      attempt[z] = buttStr;
      z++;
      //light up led so we know btn press worked
      pulseLED(yellowLed, brightness, 500);
  }
}
```